# how to change datePickerMode for individual cells in UITableViewController?

Tags: datepicker, uitableview, ios7

I'm using apples supplied sample code for iOS7 Date Cell where a tableViewController is used to display dates and modally present datePickers through an actionSheet. I have been trying to change the cells datePickerModes to datePickerModeDateAndTime, and datePickerModeTime just for learning purposes but have been unsuccessful. Right now, they are all coming up as datePickerModeDate. I am not sure which method to use to assign the datePickerModes or how to individually single out each cell to display a different picker. Would I use an if/else statement or would I assign them in a viewWillAppear method? any help is greatly appreciated. newbie here. thanks!

```
  #define kTitleKey       @"title"   // key for obtaining the data source item's title
    #define kDateKey        @"date"    // key for obtaining the data source item's date value

// keep track of which rows have date cells
#define kDateStartRow   1
#define kDateEndRow     2
#define kDateNewRow     3

static NSString *kDateCellID = @"dateCell";     // the cells with the start or end date
static NSString *kDatePickerID = @"datePicker"; // the cell containing the date picker
static NSString *kOtherCell = @"otherCell";     // the remaining cells at the end

#pragma mark -

@interface ActionSheetController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dataArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;

// keep track which indexPath points to the cell with UIDatePicker
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *datePickerIndexPath;

@property (assign) NSInteger pickerCellRowHeight;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *pickerView;

// this button appears only when the date picker is shown (iOS 6.1.x or earlier)
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;

@end

#pragma mark -

@implementation ActionSheetController

/*! Primary view has been loaded for this view controller
 */
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // setup our data source
    NSMutableDictionary *itemOne = [@{ kTitleKey : @"Name it" } mutableCopy];
    NSMutableDictionary *itemTwo = [@{ kTitleKey : @"Deadline",
                                       kDateKey : [NSDate date] } mutableCopy];
    NSMutableDictionary *itemThree = [@{ kTitleKey : @"Flashback day",
                                        kDateKey : [NSDate date] } mutableCopy];
    NSMutableDictionary *itemFour = [@{ kTitleKey : @"Flashback time",
                                        kDateKey : [NSDate date] } mutableCopy];
    NSMutableDictionary *itemFive = [@{ kTitleKey : @"" } mutableCopy];
    self.dataArray = @[itemOne, itemTwo, itemThree, itemFour, itemFive];

    self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [self.dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];    // show short-style date format
    [self.dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

    // obtain the picker view cell's height, works because the cell was pre-defined in our storyboard
    UITableViewCell *pickerViewCellToCheck = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kDatePickerID];
    self.pickerCellRowHeight = pickerViewCellToCheck.frame.size.height;
}


#define EMBEDDED_DATE_PICKER (DeviceSystemMajorVersion() >= 7)

/*! Determines if the given indexPath has a cell below it with a UIDatePicker.

 @param indexPath The indexPath to check if its cell has a UIDatePicker below it.
 */
- (BOOL)hasPickerForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BOOL hasDatePicker = NO;

    NSInteger targetedRow = indexPath.row;
    targetedRow++;

    UITableViewCell *checkDatePickerCell =
        [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:targetedRow inSection:0]];
    UIDatePicker *checkDatePicker = (UIDatePicker *)[checkDatePickerCell viewWithTag:kDatePickerTag];

    hasDatePicker = (checkDatePicker != nil);
    return hasDatePicker;
}

/*! Updates the UIDatePicker's value to match with the date of the cell above it.
 */
- (void)updateDatePicker
{
    if (self.datePickerIndexPath != nil)
    {
        UITableViewCell *associatedDatePickerCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.datePickerIndexPath];

        UIDatePicker *targetedDatePicker = (UIDatePicker *)[associatedDatePickerCell viewWithTag:kDatePickerTag];
        if (targetedDatePicker != nil)
        {
            // we found a UIDatePicker in this cell, so update it's date value
            //
            NSDictionary *itemData = self.dataArray[self.datePickerIndexPath.row - 1];
            [targetedDatePicker setDate:[itemData valueForKey:kDateKey] animated:NO];
        }
    }
}

/*! Determines if the UITableViewController has a UIDatePicker in any of its cells.
 */
- (BOOL)hasInlineDatePicker
{
    return (self.datePickerIndexPath != nil);
}

/*! Determines if the given indexPath points to a cell that contains the UIDatePicker.

 @param indexPath The indexPath to check if it represents a cell with the UIDatePicker.
 */
- (BOOL)indexPathHasPicker:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return ([self hasInlineDatePicker] && self.datePickerIndexPath.row == indexPath.row);
}

/*! Determines if the given indexPath points to a cell that contains the start/end dates.

    @param indexPath The indexPath to check if it represents start/end date cell.
*/
- (BOOL)indexPathHasDate:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BOOL hasDate = NO;

    if ((indexPath.row == kDateStartRow) || (indexPath.row == kDateNewRow) ||
        (indexPath.row == kDateEndRow || ([self hasInlineDatePicker] && (indexPath.row == kDateEndRow + 1))))
    {
        hasDate = YES;
    }

    return hasDate;
}


#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return ([self indexPathHasPicker:indexPath] ? self.pickerCellRowHeight : self.tableView.rowHeight);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self hasInlineDatePicker])
    {
        // we have a date picker, so allow for it in the number of rows in this section
        NSInteger numRows = self.dataArray.count;
        return ++numRows;
    }

    return self.dataArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    NSString *cellID = kOtherCell;

    if ([self indexPathHasPicker:indexPath])
    {
        // the indexPath is the one containing the inline date picker
        cellID = kDatePickerID;     // the current/opened date picker cell
    }
    else if ([self indexPathHasDate:indexPath])
    {
        // the indexPath is one that contains the date information
        cellID = kDateCellID;       // the start/end date cells
    }

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        // we decide here that first cell in the table is not selectable (it's just an indicator)
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    // if we have a date picker open whose cell is above the cell we want to update,
    // then we have one more cell than the model allows
    //
    NSInteger modelRow = indexPath.row;
    if (self.datePickerIndexPath != nil && self.datePickerIndexPath.row < indexPath.row)
    {
        modelRow--;
    }

    NSDictionary *itemData = self.dataArray[modelRow];

    // proceed to configure our cell
    if ([cellID isEqualToString:kDateCellID])
    {
        // we have either start or end date cells, populate their date field
        //
        cell.textLabel.text = [itemData valueForKey:kTitleKey];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:[itemData valueForKey:kDateKey]];
    }
    else if ([cellID isEqualToString:kOtherCell])
    {
        // this cell is a non-date cell, just assign it's text label
        //
        cell.textLabel.text = [itemData valueForKey:kTitleKey];
    }

    return cell;
}

/*! Adds or removes a UIDatePicker cell below the given indexPath.

 @param indexPath The indexPath to reveal the UIDatePicker.
 */
- (void)toggleDatePickerForSelectedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    NSArray *indexPaths = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:0]];

    // check if 'indexPath' has an attached date picker below it
    if ([self hasPickerForIndexPath:indexPath])
    {
        // found a picker below it, so remove it
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    else
    {
        // didn't find a picker below it, so we should insert it
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

/*! Reveals the date picker inline for the given indexPath, called by "didSelectRowAtIndexPath".

 @param indexPath The indexPath to reveal the UIDatePicker.
 */
- (void)displayInlineDatePickerForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // display the date picker inline with the table content
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    BOOL before = NO;   // indicates if the date picker is below "indexPath", help us determine which row to reveal
    if ([self hasInlineDatePicker])
    {
        before = self.datePickerIndexPath.row < indexPath.row;
    }

    BOOL sameCellClicked = (self.datePickerIndexPath.row - 1 == indexPath.row);

    // remove any date picker cell if it exists
    if ([self hasInlineDatePicker])
    {
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.datePickerIndexPath.row inSection:0]]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        self.datePickerIndexPath = nil;
    }

    if (!sameCellClicked)
    {
        // hide the old date picker and display the new one
        NSInteger rowToReveal = (before ? indexPath.row - 1 : indexPath.row);
        NSIndexPath *indexPathToReveal = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToReveal inSection:0];

        [self toggleDatePickerForSelectedIndexPath:indexPathToReveal];
        self.datePickerIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPathToReveal.row + 1 inSection:0];
    }

    // always deselect the row containing the start or end date
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    // inform our date picker of the current date to match the current cell
    [self updateDatePicker];
}

/*! Reveals the UIDatePicker as an external slide-in view, iOS 6.1.x and earlier, called by "didSelectRowAtIndexPath".

 @param indexPath The indexPath used to display the UIDatePicker.
 */
- (void)displayExternalDatePickerForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // first update the date picker's date value according to our model
    NSDictionary *itemData = self.dataArray[indexPath.row];
    [self.pickerView setDate:[itemData valueForKey:kDateKey] animated:YES];

    // the date picker might already be showing, so don't add it to our view
    if (self.pickerView.superview == nil)
    {
        CGRect startFrame = self.pickerView.frame;
        CGRect endFrame = self.pickerView.frame;

        // the start position is below the bottom of the visible frame
        startFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height;

        // the end position is slid up by the height of the view
        endFrame.origin.y = startFrame.origin.y - endFrame.size.height;

        self.pickerView.frame = startFrame;

        [self.view addSubview:self.pickerView];

        // animate the date picker into view
        [UIView animateWithDuration:kPickerAnimationDuration animations: ^{ self.pickerView.frame = endFrame; }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             // add the "Done" button to the nav bar
                             self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.doneButton;
                         }];
    }
}


#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.reuseIdentifier == kDateCellID)
    {
        if (EMBEDDED_DATE_PICKER)
            [self displayInlineDatePickerForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        else
            [self displayExternalDatePickerForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else
    {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the storyboard (MainStoryboard.storyboard) you can see they've jammed a date picker right into one of the table view cells (see "Table View Cell - datePicker"). Notice the date picker control has been given the tag 99 (and in the code this is `#define`'d as `kDatePickerTag`).

The date picker is a subview of the cell, so once you have a pointer to the cell that has the picker in it, you could get it via `viewWithTag:`, something like:

```
UIDatePicker* picker = [cell viewWithTag:kDatePickerTag];
```

You can see the sample code is doing this several places, in `hasPickerForIndexPath:` and `updateDatePicker:`. The latter is where I would jam in the call to set the picker mode, something like:

```
- (void)updateDatePicker
{
    if (self.datePickerIndexPath != nil)
    {
        UITableViewCell *associatedDatePickerCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.datePickerIndexPath];

        UIDatePicker *targetedDatePicker = (UIDatePicker *)[associatedDatePickerCell viewWithTag:kDatePickerTag];
        if (targetedDatePicker != nil)
        {
            // we found a UIDatePicker in this cell, so update it's date value
            NSDictionary *itemData = self.dataArray[self.datePickerIndexPath.row - 1];
            [targetedDatePicker setDate:[itemData valueForKey:kDateKey] animated:NO];

            // Set the picker mode.
            targetedDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Now, If I wanted to set one picker to UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime, another to UIDatePickerModeDate, and the last to UIDatePickerModeTime, is that the line/method that I would assign each cell it's own pickerMode? and would if/else be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Yep, that's the place I'd do it, and just an if/else would be fine. You could check self.datePickerIndexPath.row, and set the mode based on that.